# How to determine whether nameservers are working or not?

Tags: nameserver, ping, vagrant

During waking up Vagrant VM I have some troubles with the network in one work space, and it works fine in another one.

I'm trying to determine automatically DNS troubles (and fix it adding nameservers manually and disable PEERDNS), but the result is not stable:

```
0 ✓ vagrant 10:13:15 ~
$ ping -c 1 dl.fedoraproject.org
ping: unknown host dl.fedoraproject.org

2 ✗ vagrant 10:13:39 ~
$ time ping -c 1 dl.fedoraproject.org
PING dl.fedoraproject.org (209.132.181.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 209.132.181.25: icmp_seq=1 ttl=38 time=179 ms

--- dl.fedoraproject.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 179.362/179.362/179.362/0.000 ms

real    0m12.067s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s

0 ✓ vagrant 10:16:57 ~
$
```

In the end the exit code, of course, is "0". :(

Is there any right way to determine a problem?

Comment: Why are you using an ICMP tool to diagnose DNS issues?

Comment: Em, I don't know yet. :) What is the command name of it?

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer for this kind of questions should be STFW.
Since I'm so kind, I'll tell you that you should use `nslookup` or `dig` instead of `ping` for DNS troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for these options. But none of them is not available from the box. Without internet, I cannot install any package.

Comment: About STFW. Guys from there think this is not a STFW question. :)

Comment: Not available? Download the RPM file, upload to the VM and then install it to run.

Comment: Yeah, seem it's the only solution.